# Set default values for input objects

Tags: jquery

I use the code below to set default values for input objects. This works fine for text inputs but `select` dropdowns, radio buttons and check boxes are not reset to their default values.

How can I solve this?

```
function ResetForm(form) {

    $(":input", form).not(":button, :submit, :reset, :hidden").each(function () {
        this.value = this.defaultValue;
    });

}
```

p.s. I use this method to reset inputs which are in a `div` node; I pass the `div`'s id into this function.

Comment: did you try [form.reset()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536721(v=vs.85).aspx) ?

Comment: As I explained in my description I am passing Div and not form, I know how to reset Form but I need simmilar function for Divs

Comment: So you want to reset only part of your form and not the whole form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`defaultValue` exists for radio buttons and checkboxes, but you have misunderstood what the "value" of these elements is. It is not "which" or "whether" is selected/checked, but the underlying value that is part of the form contents *if* the element is selected/checked... whereas you want the former.

And `defaultValue` simply doesn't exist for `select`, which doesn't really have a value, but one or more selected `option` children.

You have a couple of options here.

---

#### Option 1: Wrap the inputs in a form

You said you don't have a form, but why not make it so that you do? Although the W3C spec doesn't require that inputs be under a `<form />` node, it would make sense.

Then:

```
form.reset()
```

Or, if your `form` is a jQuery element set (and it looks like it probably is):

```
form[0].reset()
```

---

#### Option 2: Hack it

If you really insist, you *can* hack it about, caching initial values using a mix of `$.attr` and `$.prop`. Make sure that you're using *jQuery 1.6.1+* though.

```
$(function() {
    prepareForm($('#myForm'));
    $('#myButton').click(function() {
       resetForm($('#myForm'));
    });
});

function prepareForm($form) {
    // Cache initial states
    $('input:checkbox, input:radio', $form).each(function() {
        $(this).prop('initial', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
    $('select', $form).each(function() {
        $(this).prop('initial', this.selectedIndex);
    });
}

function resetForm($form) {
    // Reset elements on button press
    $('input:checkbox, input:radio', $form).each(function() {
        $(this).attr('checked', $(this).prop('initial'));
    });
    $('select', $form).each(function() {
        this.selectedIndex = $(this).prop('initial');
    });
}
```

### [Live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/MpKbK/)

---

<sup>(**Note to other contributors:** I originally looked at simply resetting the element to the state specified by `$.attr`, but I guess even 1.6.1+'s `$.attr` doesn't work quite how I thought.)</sup>

Comment: Could you suggest how this function could be updated to support selects and checkboxes

Comment: @Tomas: Wrap the inputs in a form. Inputs go in a form (though 18.2.3 doesn't strictly mandate this).

Answer (score 0):

Because the value of a radio button is determined not by the "value" attribute, but by the "checked" attribute.

The following code seems to work as expected (http://jsfiddle.net/eVnMA/2/ ):

```
function reset(form)
{
    $(":input", form).not(":button, :submit, :reset, :hidden").each(function () {
        var type = $(this).attr("type");
        if(type != "radio" && type != "checkbox") this.value = this.defaultValue;
        else this.checked = $(this).data("default_value");
    });

}
$("#cb").data("default_value", null);
$("#btn").click(function(){reset("#aaa");});
```

Note that it makes no sense to use the defaultValue attribute in case of checkboxes/radio-buttons. But you can keep the desired default value by associating some data with the appropriate element.

However, I still think that the right way to achieve what you want would be to just use normal forms.

Comment: Thank you for your example. I will try it right now.
Speaking about normal form, I use ASP.NET and two forms in one web page brings many problems.

Comment: Sorry but it do not work on checkboxes and selects. Try to uncheck checkbox and click reset, it should be checked again. 
http://jsfiddle.net/eVnMA/4/

Comment: That's because you forgot to modify the default value, $("#cb").data("default_value", null); should become $("#cb").data("default_value", "checked"); in this case.

Comment: Do I need to add $("#cb").data("default_value", "checked"); for every checkbox in the form?

Comment: Well, if the default value is the same for all checkboxes, you can just do $("#aaa :checkbox").data("default_value", "checked"); (replacing #aaa with the id of the div containing your form, of course).